# Реализовать алгоритм: найти последнюю цифру некоторого n-го члена

Tags: математика, рекурсия, алгоритм

Положим, что у меня имеются значения двух первых членов последовательности и формула, рекуррентно задающая все последующие члены. Количество членов не превышает 10^1000000. Как найти последнюю цифру некоторого n-го члена?

Я решил выполнить задачу с помощью программирования. Однако вот проблема в том, что нет такого типа данных, который хранил бы столь большую величину, а она нам нужна, чтобы организовать цикл.

Comment: В общем случае — соорудите «длинное число» из нескольких обычных (подобно тому, как нормальное число составляется из цифр/битов), определите нужные арифметические операции. Или воспользуйтесь языком, в котором длинные числа встроены (например, C#, Java). Или воспользуйтесь подходящей библиотекой (например, gmp/C/C++).

Смиритесь с тем, что наивное вычисление займёт десятилетия.

В случае, если ваша рекуррентная последовательность поддаётся математической атаке (например, это линейная рекуррентная последовательность), проведите анализ и найдите решение [не в лоб](/questions/269280#269588).

Comment: @VladD 10^1000000 -- десятилетия? Вы оптимист, однако.

Comment: В Java есть тип `BigInteger` который может хранить целое неограниченной длины. А касательно рекурсии - любую рекурсию можно свести к циклу.

Answer (score 6):

В подобных случаях применяют такой подход.

Вначале доказывают, что последняя цифра числа не зависит от предыдущих - например в случае чисел Фибоначчи или если это последовательность квадратов чисел.
Потом строят последовательность для первых 10-100 элементов и ищут закономерность. Например, в случае с квадратами 0, 1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 6, 9, 4, 1

Теперь, написать код уже не сложно `f(n) = (0, 1, 4, 9, 6, 5, 6, 9, 4, 1)[n % 10];`

В случае чисел Фибоначчи этот период составляет 60 цифр

```
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 3 1 4 
5 9 4 3 7 0 7 7 4 1 
5 6 1 7 8 5 3 8 1 9
0 9 9 8 7 5 2 7 9 6 
5 1 6 7 3 0 3 3 6 9 
5 4 9 3 2 5 7 2 9 1
```

Comment: Вывел 100 чисел своей последовательности, но закономерности нет. 
Может он для формулы f(k)=f(k-2)+3f(k-3) быть больше, чем 100?

Comment: какая то странная формула. если даже первые два элемента заданы (номер один и номер два), то вычислить третий невозможно - для этого нужен нулевой. Уточните пожалуйста формулу и приведите хотя бы 5-10 первых элементов.

Comment: пересчитал, независимо от первых трех элементов, длина последовательности - 868. Потом она повторяется.

Answer (score 6):

Для вашей формулы (`f(k)=f(k-2)+3f(k-3)`) всё намного проще.

Для начала, вычисления можно делать сразу по модулю 10:

```
f(k) mod 10 сравнимо с f(k-2) mod 10 + 3 (f(k-3) mod 10) по модулю 10
```

а значит,

```
f(k) % 10 = (f(k-2) % 10 + 3 (f(k-3) % 10)) % 10
```

Перейдём к последовательности `g(k) := f(k) % 10`. Имеем:

```
g(k) = (g(k-2) + 3 * g(k-3)) % 10
```

Очевидно, что все члены последовательности, начиная с `g(k)`, зависят лишь от `g(k-1)`, `g(k-2)` и `g(k-3)`. Поскольку каждая величина `g(k-1)`, `g(k-2)`, `g(k-3)` может принимать лишь 10 различных значений, за 1000 итераций тройка значений `g(k-1)`, `g(k-2)`, `g(k-3)` повторится, а значит, последовательность зациклится.

Делайте так:

1. Определите длину цикла. Для этого прогоните 1000 итераций и найдите первый случай когда тройка (`g(k-1)`, `g(k-2)`, `g(k-3)`) впервые повторится. (Это обязательно произойдёт по [принципу Дирихле](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%B5_%28%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%29).)
2. Пусть найденная длина цикла `k`. Очевидно, что `g(N) == g(N % k)`. Поскольку `k < 1000`, а значения `g(x)` для аргумента меньше 1000 подсчитаны на предыдущем шаге, результат можно посмотреть в таблице.

Вот и всё. Дерзайте!

---

Для общей рекуррентной формулы такой простой трюк, конечно, не прокатит. Ваша последовательность и правда оказалась [линейной рекуррентной](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что Вы считаете, что для данной последовательности длина цикла меньше 100?

Comment: @KoVadim: меньше или равна.

---
Поскольку `(0, 0)` очевидно не может участвовать в последовательности, то да, строго меньше.

---
Хм, хотя вы правы, на самом деле последовательность зависит от _трёх_ членов. Сейчас поправлю.

Comment: дело в том, что я нашел длину последовательности и она больше - 868.

Comment: @KoVadim: да, уже понял, обновил ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: @VladD А можно подробнее про переход к mod 10. Это возможно потому что у нас только сложение и умножение? Или по какой то другой причине?

Comment: это возможно потому, что Вам нужна только последняя цифра.

Comment: @IronVbif: да, потому, что только сложение и умножение.

Если `x = y + 3z`, то `x % 10 == (y + 3z) %10 == ((y % 10) + 3*(z % 10)) % 10`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробности!

Я ранее не слышал о принципе Дирихле, а теперь сталь чуточку умнее.
Решение и правда красивое :)

Comment: @MathMike: пожалуйста!

Обратите внимание на рассуждение о том, что ограниченная рекуррентная последовательность всегда периодическая (и на оценку длины периода), она вам наверняка ещё пригодится. (Например, для анализа генераторов [псевдо]случайных чисел.)

Answer (score 1):

написал в виде ответа т.к. в каментарий банально не влезет, по сути является вариантом ответа предоставленого: [[@VladD](/users/10105/vladd)](/users/10105/vladd) с той лишь разницей что не прибегает сразу к испльзованию модулей

если позначить 3 первых члена последовательности как `x1,x2,x3` получается что каждый элемент последовательности можно описать функцией:

```
f(j) = a*x1 + b*x2 + c*x3 (1)
```

где `a,b,c` определяют количество вхождений элементов: `x1,x2,x3`

учитывая что нас интересует только последняя позиция в числе можно записать формулу так:

```
f(x) = a*x1 + b*x2 + c*x3 = a*x1 % 10 + b*x2 % 10 + c*x3 % 10 (2)
```

где, для каждого из чисел `a,b,c` справедлива начальная формула: `f(k)=f(k-2)+3f(k-3)`, арифметика по модулю 10 применяется для того чтоб держать множители `a,b,c` в пределах `10`, так как: `10*x % 10 = x`

пишем функцию которая в цикле считает числа `a,b,c` для каждого элемента последовательности, до тех пор пока не найдем период: `T` (3)

после того как найден период можно получить индекс элемента:

K  = (10^10000) % mod T = ...

соответственно запускаем функцию (3) еще раз, для числа `T`: получаем конкретные значения чисел `a,b,c`. далее используем формулу (1) и получаем результат

p.s. програмка пишется примерно за 30-60 минут

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, не могу прикреплять картинки, поэтому разместил свой ответ [здесь](http://yadi.sk/d/vaC4l7tIJDAzm)

[Ссылка](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/binary_pow) на алгоритм быстрого возведения в степень

Answer (score -1):

"Длинная арифметика" помогла бы. Хотя проблема будет, мне кажется, не в переменной счетчике, а в глубине рекурсии.